# Cannot connect to Secure Service Fabric cluster from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-service-fabric

I Have deployed a secure service fabric cluster and able to connect through browser and powershell using certificates. When trying the same from C# getting error as:

> An error occurred during this execution
>
> at
>   System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1
>   func, String functionTag, String functionArgs)    at
>   System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.RunInMTA(Action action)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricClient.InitializeFabricClient(SecurityCredentials
>   credentialArg, FabricClientSettings newSettings, String[]
>   hostEndpointsArg)    at
>   CloseAppAPI.Controllers.CloseClientController.d__0.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Users\kumar.kshitij\source\repos\CloseAPP\CloseAppAPI\Controllers\CloseClientController.cs:line
>   39".

Attaching Image and code for the reference. Please anyone let me know if you have a solution.

[image: screenshot]

C# Code Below:-

```
        string CommonName = "www.cluster1.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com";
        string connection = "cluster1.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com:19000";

        var xc = GetCredentials(CommonName);

            var fc = new FabricClient(xc, connection);

             static X509Credentials GetCredentials(string clientCertThumb, 
              string serverCertThumb, string name)
          {
        X509Credentials xc = new X509Credentials();
        xc.StoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;
        xc.StoreName = "Personal";
        xc.FindType = X509FindType.FindByThumbprint;
        xc.FindValue = "08DF81BD17507D4ADEC4DEE075E33A3CB8C8D04E";

        xc.RemoteCommonNames.Add(name);        

   xc.RemoteCertThumbprints.Add("3D317C232F06AC1F5A2C8D16CC2830D6F7CD5FAC");
        //xc.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
        return xc;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using different values for StoreLocation and StoreName in PowerShell.

Try replacing

`xc.StoreName = "Personal";
xc.StoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;`

with

`xc.StoreLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;
xc.StoreName = "TrustedPeople";`

Comment: I tried changing the Store location and name but getting the same error again :( is it something that Visual studio is not able to find that particular certificate

Comment: check if the thumbnail in your code has an unprinted character at its end, if you copied it from MMC. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2023835/certificate-thumbprint-displayed-in-mmc-certificate-snap-in-has-extra

Comment: i just checked that too.. still not working... can i share my screen and if you can guide me...